# Oracle SQL: exclude weekend while comparing results from previous day

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to compare the result from today to previous working day, ex:

```
select * from T1 where  ASOF = trunc(sysdate)

select * from T2 where ASOF = trunc(sysdate-1)

select  t1.asof,   t1.Count-t2.count as difference from T1,T2
```

but if there will be any weekend then i need to compare today's result with last working day(friday) dynamically, i can write this as `ASOF = trunc(sysdate-3)` but this will hardcode and will not work for last working day.

Comment: You can make a procedure to make a week like 5 days. Then, you can make a table and add holidays to that table if you want to consider holidays too. You should consider those holidays in your procedure. You can make a trigger to call the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a good rule w/o exceptions to identify a working day, use a CTE for Q1.

```
With QWD1 as (
-- select working days here ...
-- ... cdt = current working date col
),
QWD2 as (
-- select working days and prev working day for that day via LAG()...
select
-- ... cdt = current working date col
   cdt,
-- ... pdt = prev working date col
   lag(cdt, 1) over (order by cdt) as pdt
from QWD1
order by cdt
)
SELECT 
  t1.cdt as asof,
  t1.count-t2.count as Count_Difference
from QWD2 t1, QWD2 t2
where t2.cdt = t1.pdt
;
```

If you DONT have a good rule to identify a working day ... say, "if more than 8 people turn up to office w/ bad hygiene, then work is called off for that day".... then use a Table for QWD1 and populate it as needed. Use the above query with the new table instead of CTE for QWD1, Rest of the query will hold QWD2, final select etc.

HTH
Shankar

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with a `CASE` statment that depends on the current week day:

```
SELECT trunc(sysdate) - 
       CASE TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'fmDy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH')
         WHEN 'Mon' THEN 3
         WHEN 'Tue' THEN 1
         WHEN 'Wed' THEN 1
         WHEN 'Thu' THEN 1
         WHEN 'Fri' THEN 1
         WHEN 'Sat' THEN 1
         WHEN 'Sun' THEN 2
         END
  FROM DUAL;
```

I'd store both timestamps (midnight and last workday) in two variables to be consistent and better readable, but for demonstration purposes you can add it to the query:

```
SELECT * FROM employee AS OF TIMESTAMP 
    trunc(sysdate) - 
    CASE TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'fmDy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH')
         WHEN 'Mon' THEN 3
         WHEN 'Tue' THEN 1
         WHEN 'Wed' THEN 1
         WHEN 'Thu' THEN 1
         WHEN 'Fri' THEN 1
         WHEN 'Sat' THEN 1
         WHEN 'Sun' THEN 2
         END;
```